# Stipulate that only one instance of an element is allowed in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am passing some XML to a RESTful web service:

```
<root>
    <element1/>
        <element2/>
    <element3/>
</root>
```

The web service will unmarshal this XML, and I want to ensure that the XML is valid.

I used a schema to create the Java objects, and in this schema `element1` has a `maxOccurs=1` attribute but this has no effect on the Java objects that are created (unlike, for example, adding `minOccurs=1` which will result in `"required=true"` being added to the `@XMLElement` annotation). When unmarshalling the XML that is passed the web service, if an element that should appear only once appears multiple times, the last instance of the element will be parsed. I do not want this to happen, as I want to be able to alert the client that the XML they sent is not valid and that they should remove whatever element does not apply - not just arbitrarily accept the last element. I believe this will involve a little pre-validation before unmarshalling - and I may be able to make use of the beforeUnmarshal method.

After doing a bit of research, it is my understanding that there is no JAXB annotation that will allow me to specify that `element1` can exist only once. Is this the case? Is it possible to validate this at all without a schema?

Comment: Have you tried maxOccurs=1?

Comment: I generated my java classes from a schema that had maxOccurs = 1, yes. But there is nothing in the java classes to enforce this, so if there are multiple elements it parses the last one and seems to ignore the rest, when really I want an exception.

Comment: JAXB does not do schema validation. you have to manually to schema validation

Comment: @SanthoshKumarTekuri yeah I know, I only used a schema to create the Java objects. There is some validation that I have to perform after unmarshalling (for example, i have two `option` element types and only one type must be present) which is carried out in the afterUnmarshal method. But this is about XML that will be passed to my web service, I would like to validate that before I parse it to my object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked around this issue by allowing multiple instances of the element in the Java object:

```
@XmlElement(name = "element1", required = true)
private List<element1> element1;
```

This will allow me to check the size of my list in the `afterUnmarshal` method, and if the size of the list is greater than 1, I can throw a new `ValidationException`.

Answer (score 0):

Which application calling your application as it is bit difficult to do that on Java layer but you can easily do that at your web service layer where in you can define your minOccurance to 1 ad that will serve.

But if you want to do that on Java layer you need to use XML parser and then count the Occurance of particular tag but it would take a lot of time.

Comment: Hi @Kulbhushan, I have edited my question to add more clarity, as I believe my initial question may have been slightly misleading!

Comment: So, basically you need to restrict user to pass the particular tag only once. You have used maxOccurs = 1 but that only specifies the max number of count that user can pass and if user is not passing he will get an error from web service for invalid input xml and you don't need to put any extra effort. And if you want it to make it mandatory use minOccurs = 1.

Comment: A tag is required zero or one times. Unmarshalling the XML with two of the same tags does not throw any exception, only the last element is unmarshalled. I want to be able to alert the client before the unmarshalling takes place that the XML that has been sent to the web service is invalid so that they can ensure that the correct element is unmarshalled (instead of 'guessing' at the last one). I want to be able to do this without validating against the schema. Are you saying that there is no way to do this without a schema?

Comment: As for validating mandatory elements, I handle this in the afterUnmarshal method, where any missing element that `required` throws a ValidationException that can be returned to the client. I am not asking how to do this in a schema, but in my Java objects.