# Stipulate that only one instance of an element is allowed in JAXB without using the afterUnmarshal method

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to unmarshal an XML configuration file:

```
<Configuration>
    <Scenarios>
        <Scenario id="1">
            <Columns>
                <Column>COL_1</Column>
                <Column>COL_2</Column>
            </Columns>
        </Scenario>
    </Scenarios>
</Configuration>
```

Using this java class:

```
public class Scenario
{
    @NotNull
    private String _id;

    private List<String> _columns = new ArrayList<>();

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public String getId()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Column")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Columns")
    public List<String> getColumns()
    {
        return _columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(List<String> columns)
    {
        _columns = columns;
    }
}
```

I want to find a way to determine whether there are multiple occurrences of the Columns section (or no occurrence at all) in the XML file when I validate this class.

For example:

```
<Configuration>
    <Scenarios>
        <Scenario id="1">
            <Columns>
                <Column>COL_1</Column>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Column>COL_2</Column>
            </Columns>
        </Scenario>
    </Scenarios>
</Configuration>
```

Or:

```
<Configuration>
    <Scenarios>
        <Scenario id="1">
        </Scenario>
    </Scenarios>
</Configuration>
```

I cannot use any listeners as suggested in the following answer, because the JAXB unmarshalling is done in another framework which my project depends on: [How can I have JAXB call a method after it has completed unmarshalling an XML file into an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022888/1149414)

Another alternative to this is to use an in-class `afterUnmarshall` method as suggested here: [Stipulate that only one instance of an element is allowed in JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31425570/1149414) However, I cannot use it because of some in-house unwritten rules of the company I work for.

With the restrictions I have described above, I want to be able to validate this  class after it is unmarshalled, check whether there are multiple occurrences of the Columns section (or no occurrence at all) and then give appropriate error messages.

A colleague of mine has offered a solution which I am putting here as an answer. However, any other creative solution is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested solution by my colleague includes using an array instead of a collection.

```
public class Scenario
{
    @NotNull
    private String _id;

    private String[] _columns;

    private int _columnsSectionCount = 0;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public String getId()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Column")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Columns")
    public String[] getColumns()
    {
        return _columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(String[] columns)
    {
        _columns = columns;

        _columnsSectionCount++;
    }

    public int getColumnsSectionCount()
    {
        return _columnsSectionCount;
    }
}
```

By this way, I can check the `_columnsSectionCount` in the validator class to see if the `_columns` array was tried to be set more than once or was not set at all.

Note: This solution does not work at all if the type of the `_columns` variable was kept as a List.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simplest solution is to use a common JAXB class that support below xml without any extra code.

```
<Configuration>
    <Scenarios>
        <Scenario id="1">
            <Columns>
                <Column>COL_1</Column>
                <Column>COL_2</Column>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Column>COL_3</Column>
                <Column>COL_4</Column>
            </Columns>
        </Scenario>
    </Scenarios>
</Configuration>
```

in another word write a simple JAXB class that unmarshall this xml sample successfully. then check the size of 2 Lists (Columns, Column) to decide the validity of the xml file.

the validation code will be like this:

```
Configuration conf = unmarshal (sampleXml);
if (conf.getColumns().size()==0 || conf.getColumns().size()>1 )
    alarm("invalid xml file - xml must have only one 'Columns' tag.");
```

you could extend this code to implement other validation rules.

I hope this answer could help you.

Comment: this is essentially the [same solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31425570/4968796) provided in the question the OP referred to about using the afterUnmarsal method, you've just called it something else

Comment: @Atefeh Thank you for your answer. However, as I mentioned in the question, I cannot interfere with the unmarshalling part. It is done within another framework, which uses the unmarshaller of JAXB and I have to accept it as it is. Writing another unmarshaller is not an option here.

Comment: @bluesman80 
I could assume only 2 behaviors for unmarshalling part:
 
 1. It dos not accept an invalid XML and could not unmarshal it and so returns null or throws an exception.
 2. It accepts XML that is invalid and reruns it's object. 

In case one, you could interpret the null value or exception to invalidity of XML file and in case two, you could investigate the object and indicate the validity of origin XML. 

PS. "invalid xml" is an xml file that eather have more than one Column or do not have any Column tag